# React - Storing Token received from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, local-storage, token

This is something more likely as conception question. I am doing the Front-End of website and there is already created Back-end from another person. One of his endpoints is "Login endpoint" which sends me in reply several stuff:

1. Token (JWT)
2. UserId
3. Name
4. Address
5. Company

(and some others)

I receive all of them directly after login as response. So I am wondering which is the best way to save them? As we can assume it will not be a problem to save everything except Token in localStorage or in cookie with **js-cookies** package but how to store a token? It is unsafe to be stored both in local/session storage and in cookie. Currently I have Auth context which stores all of this:

```
import React from "react";

export default React.createContext({
  token: null,
  userId: null,
  address: null,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  email: null,
  company: null,
  subscription: null,
  login: (token, guid) => {},
  logout: () => {},
});
```

After login I pass it in

```
<AuthApi.Provider
        value={{
          token,
          guid,
          login,
          logout,
          address,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          email,
          company,
          subscription,
        }}
      >
```

In the App.js so they are accessible from all components inside the project with **useContext**.

As you know, when browser is refreshed we lost all the values. So basically here I don't store the values and Token also in cookie or local/session storage but I loose it after refresh. What is the best solution here if I cannot make changes in the back-end?

Comment: Are you validating tokens on the backend? Do the tokens expire? Can the tokens be revoked? Various tools from auth providers store tokens in localStorage. What are your concerns specifically around storing it there? The token is also “visible” when any requests are being made, you can really hide that.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yes, tokens are getting validated in the backend when I make a request. So basically I put a token in Authorization header.

Comment: This is a very opinion based question. You kind of need to decide how YOU want to handle tokens, whether it's session/local storage or cookies. Then you need to implement that and if you have issues/errors you can update the question to get those resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to revoke the token at any moment you can store it in Redis.
Its faster than querying the DB everytime so its a good compromise.
you can check this answer for more details [Should I store JWT tokens in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890564/should-i-store-jwt-tokens-in-redis)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too generalist and can't be answered without knowing about these details

## Questions to consider

- Does the front end communicate with different domains or servers?
- Based on the token are you doing any job in the front end? (eg: managing states like isLoggedIn). Remember other data can be cached in local storage and can be used stale while revalidate technique.
- Does the token will be expired if something like a role or name or anything else changes? (eg Custom claim in firebase is a typical example of it)
- Does your server has control over the authorisation server or you are using a third-party server like okta, firebase or something else? (if third party its ok to go with their recommendation unless you know what you are doing)
- If you disable an account in the backend how will the front end know and logout? (long-lived app includes electron or a browser extension or native app or in my case youtube which I don't remember when I closed previously)

One last note

- Cookies are more powerful than you think. For XSS attacks enable HTTPS only. But that's just the tip of the mountain. It has a lot of flags origin, same site, domain, secure flag, HTTP only, expiration etc.

In a nutshell token !== userInfo. You can't treat both in a similar way.

Answer (score -1):

In React use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) with its [Redux Persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist). By using these libraries the token is not disappear on page refresh. And also you don't need to pass AUTH token to child components as by storing Token as a state in redux it accessible in all components.

Comment: I think redux is also easy visible from browser or I am wrong?

Comment: you can hide it by just putting an if for production

Comment: check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909402/how-to-exclude-disable-redux-devtools-in-production-build-or-disconnect

Answer (score -1):

As for me the best way is to create double tokens authorization (access and refresh tokens), store tokens in LocalStorage and then refresh tokens by delay or requests.
Just ask your backend developer to add one route for tokens refresh.
For refreshing you can use axios interceptors.

[Refresh token functionality in React application using redux and redux-saga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738745/refresh-token-functionality-in-react-application-using-redux-and-redux-saga)

Comment: I wrote on purpose the last sentence - "What is the best solution here if I cannot make changes in the back-end?". I am very aware of the solutions if I can make changes in the back-end